# IBM FileNet ExtendedInputStream examples

Tags: filenet-p8, filenet-content-engine

I have a file of size 40 MB in filenet-p8. I see that from v5.2.1 there is a new API `ExtendedInputStream` can anyone share an example of it. I see its not a concrete class so how can I extend and make use of it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [5.2.1 What's new for developers](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGLW6_5.2.1/com.ibm.p8.relnotes.doc/wn_cpe_dev.htm):

> Using the new extended stream support, your application can more efficiently retrieve **very large file content—such as video and audio content**—from any point in the file. No changes are needed to existing applications that do not need this capability. For applications that do require this capability, **you can cast the input stream returned from the current accessContentStream method** (on the ContentTransfer, Document, and Annotation classes) to the new extended class to invoke the new operations.

So it looks like you would do something like this:

```
Document document = Factory.Document.fetchInstance(objectStore, pathToDocument, null);    
ExtendedInputStream inputStream = (ExtendedInputStream) document.accessContentStream(arg0);
```

From there you will have access to the new methods on the 
[ExtendedInputStream](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGLW6_5.2.1/com.ibm.p8.ce.dev.java.doc/com/filenet/api/util/ExtendedInputStream.html).